# SQL Server querying system objects

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, system-tables

I have a stored procedure in my Master Database. It is used by external programs which provide all of the parameters. One of the parameters provided is a database name. Within that database there ought to be a table named `xyz`.

I receive an exception when that table does not exist in the requested database. I would like to write something into the stored procedure to check if that table exists and return something more useful if it doesn't exist.

This is trickier than it seems. I can get by variable database names using dynamic SQL. And I can check if those databases exist using `IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM SYS.DATABASES WHERE NAME = PARAMETER1)`.

In order to check if the table exists, I would need to `USE` the database, so I would need to use dynamic SQL. However, that would leave me with an executable variable and I don't know how to check the results of that variable (for instance, I could not do `IF EXISTS (EXEC @SQL)`). I was hoping there was some way to say `SELECT * FROM sys.AllDatabasesAllTables WHERE DatabaseName = Parm1 AND TableName = Parm2`.

I realize that `sys.AllDatabasesAllTables` does not exist, but I was hoping maybe someone knew of another way... Is there a good way to make a view in the `master` database that stores all databases and their table names?

Comment: You could make a view in master that does a union of sys.tables and sys.columns for each database but it wouldn't be dynamic. To be honest that sounds like a maintenance nightmare and something I would run away from immediately if not sooner. I would think that using dynamic sql would be better in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the [`OBJECT_ID`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190328.aspx) as like below:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('DatabaseName.SchemaName.TableName') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
 -- Code Here
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 -- Code Here
END
GO
```

Another possible solution, but not tested though is to use a kind of [Try-Catch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms175976.aspx) statement?

```
BEGIN TRY
     { sql_statement | statement_block }
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
     [ { sql_statement | statement_block } ]
END CATCH
```

So in the catch block, you could return the message you were looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Use function OBJECT_ID() as seen in the documentation?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms190328.aspx